# How to judge whether a file is a nv12 format file?

Tags: format, yuv, nv12-nv21

I have a file, I want to know whether it is NV12 format, how to judge a file is a nv12 format file? Is there any tool or test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `mplayer` The following should work (here I'm assuming a CIF-size, i.e 352, 288)

```
$ mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=352:h=288:format=nv12 file.yuv
```

To convert from. let's say 4:2:0 plane separated (a.k.a YV12, which pretty much is the standard) you can use `ffmpeg`:

```
$ ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 352x288 -i foreman_352x288.yuv -pix_fmt nv12 foreman_nv_12.yuv
```

yuv is a raw-data format without any headers so there's nothing you really can do than to try viewing it using different format until you manage to find a match.

Some basic consistency checks though are that NV12 is a `4:2:0`format meaning that the chroma-planes are subsampled a factor 2 in both width and height and this gives a total byte count for one frame:

```
width * height * 3 / 2
```

this you can check against the total number of bytes for the file.

Comment: Hi, been trying to use this conversion, but I can't play the nv12 with the player. on converting with ffmpeg to other format it works OK.

Comment: which player are you referring to? Using ffmpeg, this should work `ffplay -s 352x288 -pix_fmt nv12 file.yuv`

Comment: thanks. I've must had an issue with buggy old version ffmpeg. I did the conversion and played it eventually

Comment: 7yuv is useful for nv12 (and other) conversions

Comment: or you can use my excellent python tool to do format conversion :-) https://github.com/figgis/yuv-tools